# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchMembers' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

i got this erroe even the command is working fine
(node:1907) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchMembers' of undefined

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    let guild = await message.guild.cache.fetchMembers();
    let roleID= '644235497169748037';
    let roleID1= '615852982734684181';
    let roleID2= '615852983330013212';
    let roleID3= '615852992230588427';
    let roleID4= '722513324151144552';

    let memberCount = guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size;
    let memberCount1 = guild.roles.get(roleID1).members.size;
    let memberCount2 = guild.roles.get(roleID2).members.size;
    let memberCount3 = guild.roles.get(roleID3).members.size;
    let memberCount4 = guild.roles.get(roleID4).members.size;

    let memberCountChannel = guild.channels.get("733035179756486737")
    let memberCountChannel1 = guild.channels.get("732530240420839464")
    let memberCountChannel2 = guild.channels.get("732530312713863178")
    let memberCountChannel3 = guild.channels.get("732530713898909746")
    let memberCountChannel4 = guild.channels.get("732530791686602833")

    memberCountChannel.setName("Guild Members: " + memberCount)
    memberCountChannel1.setName("Wizard: " + memberCount1)
    memberCountChannel2.setName("Witch: " + memberCount2)
    memberCountChannel3.setName("Shai: " + memberCount3)
    memberCountChannel4.setName("Compass: " + memberCount4)

 });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0):

Discord JS v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods such as `Collection#get` on data structures like `Client#users`. You will now have to directly ask for a cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods.

---

You need to change:

```js
guild.roles.get(roleID)
// to
guild.roles.cache.get(roleID)
```

and:

```js
guild.channels.get(channelID)

// to
guilds.channels.cache.get(channelID)
```

---

Another error I saw in your code is that you are trying to access the property `cache` of Guild, which is nonexistent (`message.guild.cache.fetchMembers()`).

You'll have to use:

```js
message.guild.members.fetch()
```

Comment: iam using now V12 thats why i used cache still getting same error

Comment: Alright. I'll update my answer for V12 in a few moments.

Comment: If it is the same error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchMembers' of undefined) please try to change `message.guild.cache.fetchMembers()` to `message.guild.members.fetch()`.

Comment: new error
`(node:4019) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
`